# Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome - Multiple messages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I am currently working on a Chrome extension which uses the chrome.pushMessaging API provided by Chrome.

I register push messaging callback in the background page of the extension:

```
chrome.pushMessaging.onMessage.addListener(pushMessageReceivedCallback);
```

The problem is that the pushMessageReceivedCallback gets hit immediately with the last four messages that were sent to the extensions channel ID. This behaviour seems the same on on computer I use.

Is there some way if consuming GCM messages? Once I have seen the message once, I don't want it to keep arriving every time the extension is loaded.

Thanks.